# Counter example that Egoroff's Theorem does not hold for infinite measure domain

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

In Real Analysis, [Egoroff's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem) stated that:

"Assume $E$ has finite measure. Let ${f_n}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on $E$ that converges pointwise on E to the real-valued function $f$. Then for each $\epsilon >0$, there is a closed set F contained in $E$ for which ${f_n} \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $F$ and $m(E \setminus F) < \epsilon$.

I would like to prove that if the domain of functions does not have finite measure, then Egoroff's Theorem does not hold. I tried to find a counter example but I can not.

Comment: $f_n(x) = x/n$?

Comment: Do you mean that the domain is $[0, \infty)$?

Comment: Or $\mathbb{R}$. More generally, every measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with infinite Lebesgue measure works as the domain for that example.

Comment: See also: [Egorov's Theorem - Counterexample in Infinite Case](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/358786)