# Understanding the indicator function counterexample to Egorov's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, examples-counterexamples

I am trying to find an example that shows that Egorov's Theorem fails when the measure of the set under study is not finite. I found this example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358786/egorovs-theorem-counterexample-in-infinite-case/1972533):

> Set $\forall n\geq1: f_n:[0,\infty[\to\{0,1\}, f_n:=\chi_{[n-1,n]}$. Then $f_n\to0$ pointwise on $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $\exists F\subseteq\mathbb{R}: f_n\stackrel{u.}{\to}0$ on $F$, i.e. that
>
> $$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists N,\forall n\geq N,\forall x\in F: |f_n(x)|<\epsilon.$$
>
> For $\epsilon:=1, \exists N,\forall n\geq N,\forall x\in F:|f_n(x)|<1$, so that $x\not\in[N,\infty[$. Thus $F\subseteq [0,N[$, and consequently $m(\mathbb{R}-F)\geq m([N,\infty[)=\infty$.

There is one thing I don't understand about this proof. I understand how the author got to $F\subseteq [0,N[$. How does this imply that $m(\mathbb{R}-F)\geq m([N,\infty[)=\infty$? I thought that $F\subseteq [0,N[ \implies F^c \subseteq [N, \infty) \implies m\{F^c\} \le m\{[N, \infty)\}$, where the last implication follows from the fact that measure preserve order, but this conclusion is almost the opposite of what the proof concluded. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A\subseteq B$ implies $B^{c}\subseteq A^{c}$.

Comment: Wow, much simpler than I thought. Just out of curiosity, is there a name for this result?

Comment: I think I never ever see there is any title to that.